# How do I organize a project with a shared library in Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am wondering if this the correct way to structure my project and how I can configure it so that I can build/test/package all of its individual components from a single build command?

I have a Maven project that contains multiple modules- Spring apps and a "library" shared between them as a dependency. I would like to be able to build all the apps together with the library so that I can execute integration tests whenever any of the modules change (lib or app).

Ideally, I should be able to compile each component, run unit tests per app/library, run integration tests, package each component into its executable jar. At some point, this process will be run on a Jenkins server with higher-level system tests.

Right now, I am using `mvn clean install spring-boot:repackage`. This works for each app individually,i.e. when running from `Main Project/App1/`. However, when I run it from the project root `Main Project/`, I am getting an error that the library cannot be spring-repackage'd because the library does not have a main class. This is fine- it's a library, it does not need an entry point.

So is this the correct way to structure a multi-app project in Maven or am I doing something very wrong?

The project structure is:

```
Main Project
|-SharedLibrary/
  |-src/
  |-pom.xml
|-App1/
  |-src/
  |-pom.xml
|-App2/
  |-src/
  |-pom.xml
|-App3/
  |-src/
  |-pom.xml
|-pom.xml
```

Comment: Do you have added the apps as modules in the main-project pom?

Comment: Hi Christian, yes, all the tests get run when I execute `mvn clean install` against the main project. However, only the library artefact gets built correctly as all the others need to be built with `mvn clean install spring-boot:repackage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running the goal on the command line, consider adding configuration for the [Spring Boot maven plugin repackage goal](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html) to the POMs. If the configuration is added, the repackage will run as part of the `mvn clean install` command.

First, add the plugin to the parent's POM in the `pluginManagement` section. This will ensure the version of Spring boot is consistent for all modules.

```
<pluginMangement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>YourSpringBootVersion</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginMangement>
```

Then add the `repackage` goal to the POMs for the Spring Boot modules. The goal binds to phase `package` by default, per the docs.

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>spring-boot-repackage</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>repackage</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Alternately, since the app is using `repackage` in 3 of the 4 modules, you may add the configuration above to the parent. But, doing so executes the plugin goal for all modules which we know won't work. So, if you choose this option, then you need to tell the plugin *not* to run in the library:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>spring-boot-repackage</id>
        <phase>none</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>repackage</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Note the addition of the `<phase>none</phase>`. This disables the plugin goal for this module only.

Comment: This solved my problem fully- I knew that I was trying to do something quite simple.

I picked the approach of specifying the build process for each component in its own pom separately, rather than assuming that each component would be built the same way. The justification is that the build process is not very complicated at the moment and it doesn't get iterated over as often as the source or the dependencies.

I.e., one can tell maven "go build my project" and then each artifact is responsible for specifying how it is supposed to be built.